# Difficulty with query involving multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, left-join

My table:

- `players (id_player, id_team)`
- `playerLogros (id_logro, id_player, TD, id_match)` TD is the number of touchdowns scored by a player
- `matchs (id_match, status)` Status explains if the game has finished
- `team_match (id_team, id_match, tipo)` tipo:Local/Visitante

I need to know how many games a team has won. It depends on the TD scored by both teams in a match.

I cannot change the structure of the DB. I can get the TDs scored by one team, but, at the same time, I don't know how to get the TDs scored by the other team.

My current query:

```
SELECT SUM(playerLogros.TD)
FROM playerLogros
LEFT JOIN players ON players.id_player=playerLogros.id_player
LEFT JOIN team_match ON team_match.id_team=players.id_team
LEFT JOIN matchs ON matchs.id_match = team_match.id_match
WHERE matchs.status='ended'
GROUP BY...
```

Here you have some samples:

```
INSERT INTO players (id_player, id_team) VALUES 
(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), 
(5,1), (6,1), (7,1), (8,1), 
(9,1), (10,1), (11,1), (12,2), 
(13,2), (14,2), (15,2), (16,2), 
(17,2), (18,2), (19,2), (20,2), 
(21,2), (22,2), (23,4), (24,4), 
(25,4), (26,4), (27,4), (28,4), 
(29,4), (30,4), (31,4), (32,4), 
(33,4), (34,5), (35,5), (36,5), 
(37,5), (38,5), (39,5), (40,5), 
(41,5), (42,5), (43,5), (44,5);

INSERT INTO  playerLogros (id_logro, id_player, TD, id_match) VALUES
(1,2,1,1), (2,10,1,1), (3,15,1,1), (4,29,2,2), (5,38,1,2), 
(6,6,1,3), (7,32,1,3), (8,16,1,4), (9,1,1,5), (10,42,1,5), (11,35,1,5),
(12,25,3,6), (13,28,1,6), (14,15,1,6), (15,29,1,6);

INSERT INTO matchs (id_match, status) VALUES
(1,'ended'),(2,'ended'),(3,'ended'),(4,'ended'),(5,'ended'),(6,'ended');

INSERT INTO team_match (id_team, id_match, tipo) VALUES 
(1,1,'Local'),(2,1,'Visitant'),(4,2,'Local'),(5,2,'Visitant'),
(1,3,'Local'),(4,3,'Visitant'),(2,4,'Local'),(5,4,'Visitant'),
(1,5,'Local'),(5,5,'Visitant'),(4,6,'Local'),(2,6,'Visitant');
```

And the query should give something like this:

id_team...Matches_won...Matches_tied...Matches_lost

...1................1.......................1......................1

...2................1.......................0......................2

...4................2.......................1......................0

...5................1.......................0......................2

Comment: where are you stating that a goal belongs to a specific game?  I only see when a goal belongs to a player.  What is id_partido?

Comment: a sqlFiddle would be helpful with some sample data

Comment: erl, sorry Kritner. Translation problem, I forgot to change a thing. Now it is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get it for you.  The pre-query does aggregations on per team (based on player association to scoring for a given match) and grouping by each team and match combination.  So at the end, you would have 2 records for a match, one for each respective team.

From that, join back to the matches table to find the corresponding Local vs Visitor team ID and get respective value... grouping by the match so it is rolled-up to a single row per match.

```
SELECT 
      PreSumTDs.id_match,
      MAX( IF( tm.tipo = 'Local', tm.id_team, 0 )) as LocalTeam,
      SUM( IF( tm.tipo = 'Local' and tm.id_team = PreSumTDs.id_team, PreSumTDs.TeamTDs, 0 )) as LocalScore,
      MAX( IF( tm.tipo = 'Visitante', tm.id_team, 0 )) as VisitTeam,
      SUM( IF( tm.tipo = 'Visitante' and tm.id_team = PreSumTDs.id_team, PreSumTDs.TeamTDs, 0 )) as VisitScore
   from 
      ( select 
              pl.id_match,
              p.id_team,
              SUM( pl.TD ) as TeamTDs
           from
              matchs m
                 JOIN playerLogros pl
                    ON m.match_id = pl.match_id
                 JOIN players p
                    ON pl.id_player = p.id_player
           where
              m.status = 'ended'
           group by
              pl.id_match,
              p.id_team ) PreSumTDs
      JOIN team_match tm
         ON PreSumTDs.id_match = tm.id_match
   group by
      tm.id_match
```

Comment: does iif exist in mysql?

Comment: Thanks DRapp, I'll check it tomorrow and I'll tick it ;)

Comment: Wow, LocalTeam is ok, LocalScore is ok, VisitTeam is ok, BUT VisitScore is not. I do not get it. I do not understand the use of SUM in the main query.

Comment: @nanmaniac, revised query for explicit Visitante reference for visitors team/score.

Comment: Great!! Now I'm working with a really very big query that gives me the classification chart... You opened my eyes!! Thank you!